# Compare two person columns in a list with Multiple values in person coulmn SharePoint designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I am trying to create SharePoint 2013 designer workflow for Task List .

In My case I have to send mail to task assigned to person if there is a  change in the task by another person except from the Assigned To person.

For that I am comparing two columns: Assigned To and Modified By.

If there are more than one person present in Assigned To column then how can we compare these two columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to find solution for this.I hope it will help someone.

[image]

Thanks,

Sachin Shinde

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Some Modification has been done